# using python how to find ^M

Tags: python

```
files=os.listdir(path)
for f in files:
filepath=os.path.join(path,f)
myfile=open(filepath,'r')
s=myfile.read()
myfile.close()
p=s.find('^M')
if p == -1:
    continue
print  f ,' ',p,' ',len(s)
```

I want to find all files containing ^M: but it can not work

```
File "fix2.py", line 13
    p=s.find('
          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

What should I do to find that? Thank you very much!

Comment: That is a carriage return, `\r` should do the trick.  (Not tested)

Comment: Are you sure that it's the same code in your file. Why the error message have only.  `p=s.find('` ?

Comment: `EOL while scanning string literal` is implicating that your string literal '^M' is spanning over more than one line.